# How to get the sum of all the divisors of a number, without including it

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
print(func(6)) # Should be 1+2+3=6
print(func(12)) # Should be 1+2+3+4+6=16
```

I wrote a function that returns just a list of all dividers of a number

```
def func(num):
    add=[]
    for i in range(1,num-1):
        if num%i==0:
            add.append(i)
    print(add)
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking.

Comment: I need to write a function func that will make such output print(func(6)) # Should be print out 1+2+3=6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def func(num):
    add = []
    total_sum = 0
    for i in range(1, num - 1):
        if num % i == 0:
            add.append(str(i))
            total_sum += i

    return "{}={}".format("+".join(add), total_sum)
```

Comment: TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, int found

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this:

```
def func(num):
    add = [i for i in range(1, num-1) if num % i == 0]
    return sum(add)
```

This code gives:

```
print(func(6))  # Should be 1+2+3=6
print(func(12)) # Should be 1+2+3+4+6=16
```

Answer (score 2):

Returns the sum of the divisors:

```
def sum_divisors(n):
  sum = 0
  x = 1
  while n != 0 and x < n :
      
    if n % x == 0  :
      sum += x
    else:
      sum += 0
    x += 1    
  
  return sum
```

Answer (score 0):

So im not sure this is exactly what you want. But you can get the sum of a list using sum() in python so your function looks like this

```
def func(num):
    add=[]
    for i in range(1,num-1):
        if num%i==0:
            add.append(i)
    return sum(add)
```

This returns the correct output with

```
print(func(6)) # Should be 1+2+3=6
print(func(12)) # Should be 1+2+3+4+6=16
```

it can also be written as a list comprehension as such

```
def list_func(num):
    return sum([i if num%i==0 else 0 for i in range(1, num-1)])
```

Comment: I don't need to count some of divisors, I need just to print it. That the output of func(6) will be 1+2+3=6

Comment: @AnnaTum So you want the output as a string?

Comment: Yes it should be like a string